# Pointing the root domain to Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns

I have an app on Heroku, but I can't get the naked root domain to work.

I have a CNAME record for www.mydomain.com pointing to my app.herokuapp.com

I can't create a CNAME for mydomain.com, domain provider tells me I need to do it through an A record, that points to my IP address.

So, since Heroku won't give me that IP address, how can I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: This is covered in their documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-root-domains

Comment: This question has been answered in detail here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533341/https-redirect-from-root-domain-i-e-apex-or-naked-to-www-subdomain-withou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533341/https-redirect-from-root-domain-i-e-apex-or-naked-to-www-subdomain-withou)

Answer (score 0):

DNS RFC (RFC1033) requires the "zone apex" (sometimes called the "root domain" or "naked domain") to be an "A Record," not a CNAME.

CloudFlare provides a feature called `CNAME Flattening` which essentially solves this problem for you.

Read more: https://blog.cloudflare.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-root-domain-cname-supp/